# Can I declare global/general methods in mongoose schema?

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose

Is it possible to stash methods in schema of mongoose so any schemas or some group of schemas can access and use those methods, like encryption of passwords and stuff?

```
//I mean something like this
const Schema = require('monogoose').Schema
Schema.statics.method = function(){
   //some logic
}
```

If it's not possible, what can I do to avoid repeating my code at encryptions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to attach a function to `Schema` object to make it accessible to your models. You can always define the function in a file and require it and use them in your models.